# Complementary angles in radians

Tags: trigonometry

I just have a really basic question about complementary angles.

I was working on a problem(complex numbers). I was asked to find the rotation angle. And the answer was different based on which quadrant the coordinates were in. If it were in the first quadrant, the answer would be ex) $\frac\pi6$. If It were in the third quadrant, it would be $-5\pi/6$.

So my question is

$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$\tan\left(-\frac{5\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Are $\frac\pi6$ and $-\frac{5\pi}{6}$ complementary angles?

How would I get $-\frac{5\pi}{6}$ if I were to know $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two angles are *complementary* if the sum of their measures is $\pi/2$ (or $90^\circ$).

The angles $\pi/6$ and $-5\pi/6$ are not complementary since their sum is not $\pi/2$.

You correctly found that a particular solution of the equation 
$$\tan x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \tag{1}$$
is 
$$x = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
Since the tangent function assumes each real value exactly once in each period, any two solutions of equation 1 differ by an integer multiple of the period of the tangent function.  Since the period of the tangent function is $\pi$, the set of all solutions of equation 1 is 
$$x = \frac{\pi}{6} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
In particular, if $n = -1$, we obtain the solution
$$x = \frac{\pi}{6} - \pi = -\frac{5\pi}{6}$$

Comment: if the coordinates were in the second quadrant, would the angle be negative? what about the fourth quadrant?

Comment: In the second and fourth quadrants, the tangent function assumes negative values.  Whether the angles are positive or negative depends on how you measure them (in the counterclockwise or clockwise directions).